# How to ensure ssh via cgroups on centos?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

When some cpu-intensive processes are running on the server, chances are that we could not log in to this machine with error 'operation timeout' via `ssh` command.

According to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56538/controlling-priority-of-applications-using-cgroups) answered by peterph, there should be a way to guarantee sshd service on any circumstances. But I just don't know how to **create a group for sshd, give it some non-negligible CPU time share, and give this "remote access" processes much higher CPU share then the rest**.

Could anyone tell me how can I configure it in "/etc/cgconfig.conf" and "/etc/cgrules.conf"? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

alter the sshd init.d script so that sshd runs with a negative (higher priority) nice value

Find the ssh command in the "start" section and add "/usr/bin/nice -10" in front of it

Comment: Could you write it in more details plz? where's init.d and start section?